# Ag-grid Tree drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, treeview, drag, ag-grid

Does the ag-grid tree-table support drag-and-drop?

Cannot find it in here so far: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree/#gsc.tab=0

Meaning dragging nodes into other nodes and dragging to change order.

(I know columns can be dragged; which is nice, but not what I'm asking here, just to clarify)

Comment: Ag-grid added the Tree data example combined with drag and drop here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-dragging/#row-dragging-tree-data

Answer (score 1):

Ag-grid has added [docs and example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-dragging/#row-dragging--tree-data) on DnD for tree tables